# Find the average length of the preceding word of another word in a string of text

Tags: function, loops, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function **prevword_ave_len(word)** that takes a string arugment **word** and returns the average length in characters of the word that precedes **word** in the text.

The text is the first paragraph of Moby Dick:

> Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - never mind how long precisely - having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off - then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. This is my substitute for pistol and ball. With a philosophical flourish Cato throws himself upon his sword; I quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. If they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other, cherish very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me.

There are a few special requirements to be aware of:

1. If **word** happens to be the first word occurring in the text, then the length of the preceding word for that occurrence should be counted as 0.
2. If **word** is not in the text then the function should return False.
3. A "word" is simply a string that is delimited by "whitespace." Punctuation following a word is included as part of the word.
4. The casing in the original text and in **word** should be preserved.

How would I go about doing this? My thought process was to split the text into a list of words and then use a for loop to search for each instance of **word**, and where word is found, somehow index the word before **word**, find its length and add it to an empty list. Then I would average the elements in this list and then that would be my output. I just don't know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a dictionary, which values are lists of the lengths of all preceding words. 
The given example print the solution for word `the` (last line).

In case you are not familiar with `defaultdict` take a look  [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def  prevword_ave_len(word, text):

    words = defaultdict(list)    #initialization of default dictionary

    textlist = text.split()      #split text into words
    words[textlist[0]].append(0) #append 0 for first word in text
    #iterate over words, append length of preceding word to values
    for i in range(1,len(textlist)):
        words[textlist[i]].append(len(textlist[i-1]))

    if word in words:
        return sum(words[word])/len(words[word])    #calculate mean
    else: return False

if __name__ == "__main__":

    text = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago - never mind how long precisely - having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically knocking people's hats off - then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. This is my substitute for pistol and ball. With a philosophical flourish Cato throws himself upon his sword; I quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. If they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other, cherish very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me."

    print(prevword_ave_len('the', text))
```